# MongoDB / NodeJS - Data Insert Doesn't Auto Increment Object_ID

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hi There: I'm new to Node.JS, MongoDB, and Mongoose so please forgive me if my questions are naive.

I've wrote a small bit of code to asyncronously send data from a form to the database and then display back on the client.

The inserts are kind of working. Each time I perform a form submission my data is inserted into the DB, but used the same ObjectID each time, meaning that no increment is happening on the document ID.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Should I be manually incrementing the ID or is there a different way to handle objects/inserts/etc. with these technologies.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Code:

```js
// Launch express and server
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

//connect to DB
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/napkin_v1');

//Configure Node w/ Dependencies
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(require("stylus").middleware({
      src: __dirname + "/public",
      dest: __dirname + "/public",
      compress: false
    }));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  //app.use(require('stylus').middleware({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});


// Define Schema for Message
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var messageSchema = new Schema({
    body: { type: String, index: { unique:true}},
    user: { type: String, index: { unique:true}},
    dateCreated: Date,
    tags: String
});

mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
var Message = mongoose.model('Message');

//Insert First Message into DB

var message = new Message();


app.get('/', function(req,res){
  Message.find(function(error, docs){
    res.render('layout.jade', {
      locals: {
        title: 'Napkin v0.111',
        messages: docs
      }
    });
  })
})

app.post('/', function(req,res){
  message.user = req.param('user');
  message.body = req.param('body');
  message.save(function() {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});

//Launch Server
app.listen(3002);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d", app.address().port);
```

Comment: here is a demo which shows the basic Add, Edit, Delete, Update functionality http://goo.gl/HlbXE

Answer (score 1):

Your message instance is global, so you're not creating new messages. You need to do var message = new Message(); inside the root post function.

Answer (score 0):

Just after `var Schema = mongoose.Schema`, I guess you will need this `var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;`